# google play service crash (gmaps)

Tags: android, google-maps, google-play-services

I'm using google maps in my android application and I recently got a crash from a Samsung Device running android 6.0.

This is the exception I am receiving:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference
   at maps.d.d$c$1.a(:com.google.android.gms.alldynamite:102)
   at maps.d.f$1.findAccessibilityNodeInfosByText(:com.google.android.gms.alldynamite:50)
   at android.view.AccessibilityInteractionController.findAccessibilityNodeInfosByTextUiThread(AccessibilityInteractionController.java:356)
   at android.view.AccessibilityInteractionController.access$700(AccessibilityInteractionController.java:54)
   at android.view.AccessibilityInteractionController$PrivateHandler.handleMessage(AccessibilityInteractionController.java:1200)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7229)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

Any idea what is causing this?

My Code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Fabric.with(this, new Answers(), new Crashlytics());
    setContentView(R.layout.place_picker);
    //Retrieve Map fragment
    mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
```

}

```
 @Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onMapReady. ");
    googleMap = map;

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        requestLocationPermissions();

    } else {
        configureMap();
        startLocationUpdates();
    }
}
```